# jQuery avoid on change to be triggered when done programatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a basic invoicing system, where we can select an item (jquery select 2), which on change fills in the base price, units per ctn etc in the form. We can change this price before saving the invoice.

if I need to edit this (saved) invoice (in the same page and form), I'd get the id with PHP GET and then fetch the invoice saved in mysql with ajax, to get the item and its qty, price etc details to be filled in the form.

Now the problem is, (after ajax) when I programatically select the item in select box (jquery select 2), it triggers the on change function (as stated earlier) and gets the base price etc in the form, instead of the one I want to fill programatically to see and then change it.

```
//Fetch Items
fetchItems()

function fetchItems() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/4z7se',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(items) {
      // Create list of items in select tag
      var toAppend = '';
      $.each(items, function(i, o) {
        toAppend += '<option value="' + o.itemId + '">' + o.newName + '</option>';
      });

      $('#item').append(toAppend);
      $('#item').select2({
        placeholder: "Select an item",
        escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
          return markup;
        }
      })
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError);
    }
  });
}



// On item select, get item details and fill in the table
// --->>> Select first item for this demo to get the details filled (usually  it requests the values from mysql for the selected item)
$('#item').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/vjfi',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      // Print item details in respective elements
      $('#itemId').val(data[0]['itemId'])
      $('#size').text(data[0]['size'])
      $('#units_per_ctn').text(data[0]['units_per_ctn'])
      $('#ctn_price').val(data[0]['ctn_price'])
      $('#qty').val('') // Clear qty from previous
      $('#total_price').text('') // Clear total price from previous
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError);
    }
  });
})


// For update purpose, details to be filled in the form
$('#edit').click(function() {
  //var editId = '<?PHP if(isset($_GET['edit '])) { echo $_GET['edit'];}?>';
  var editId = 1 // Lets assume it for this demo
  if (editId > 0) {
    // Get transfer details for this id
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1iwha',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $('table #item').select2().val(data[0]['item_id']).trigger('change')

        // Here is the proble, can't put these values in the input because as soon as select2 change is triggered it fills its own values to the inputs. But I want the following values (returned from mysql in json) to be filled in.
        $('table #ctn_price').val(data[0]['ctn_price'])
        $('table #qty').val(data[0]['qty'])
        $('table #totap_price').val(data[0]['total_price'])
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError);
      }
    })
  }
})
```

> Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jno58c6y/)

Comment: Why not remove the `.trigger('change')` then?!

Comment: that is required when creating a new invoice

Comment: because this is a same page to add and edit invoice

Comment: Then separate them?

Comment: still need this functionality, if editing invoice require to change item, then its price, units per ctn needs to be retrieved (which are done with on change function)

Comment: @eisbehr: i just got ur point now, but removing `.trigger` doesn't select the selected option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `triggerHandler` and return the `$.ajax` object in your `event listener`. Then you can chain `.done()` and do your work after ajax request has finished.

```
// return ajax object
$('#item').on('change', function() {
    return $.ajax({
        /* ... */
    });
});

// chain actions
$('#item').select2().val(val).triggerHandler('change').done(function() {
    // set your values
});
```

**[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jno58c6y/1/):**

```js
//Fetch Items
fetchItems()

function fetchItems() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/4z7se',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(items) {
      // Create list of items in select tag
      var toAppend = '';
      $.each(items, function(i, o) {
        toAppend += '<option value="' + o.itemId + '">' + o.newName + '</option>';
      });

      $('#item').append(toAppend);
      $('#item').select2({
        placeholder: "Select an item",
        escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
          return markup;
        }
      })
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError);
    }
  });
}



// On item select, get item details and fill in the table
// --->>> Select first item for this demo to get the details filled (usually  it requests the values from mysql for the selected item)
$('#item').on('change', function() {
 return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/vjfi',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      // Print item details in respective elements
      $('#itemId').val(data[0]['itemId'])
      $('#size').text(data[0]['size'])
      $('#units_per_ctn').text(data[0]['units_per_ctn'])
      $('#ctn_price').val(data[0]['ctn_price'])
      $('#qty').val('') // Clear qty from previous
      $('#total_price').text('') // Clear total price from previous
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError);
    }
  });
});

// For update purpose, details to be filled in the form
$('#edit').click(function() {
  //var editId = '<?PHP if(isset($_GET['edit '])) { echo $_GET['edit'];}?>';
  var editId = 1 // Lets assume it for this demo
  if (editId > 0) {
    // Get transfer details for this id
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1iwha',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $('table #item').select2().val(data[0]['item_id']).triggerHandler("change").done(function() {
          $('table #ctn_price').val(data[0]['ctn_price'])
          $('table #qty').val(data[0]['qty'])
          $('table #totap_price').val(data[0]['total_price'])
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError);
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered jambo_table">
  <thead>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Units/CTN</th>
    <th>CTN Price
      <br><small>(inc GST)</small></th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="size"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="item" name="item">
          <option disabled selected>Select an item</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="units_per_ctn"></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ctn_price" name="ctn_price" size="10">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" name="qty" size="10">
      </td>
      <td id="total_price"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
  Normally item id is received with php get, and the details are fetched with ajax to be filled in this form, (using button for the demo only)<br>
  <button id="edit">Edit Record 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i have this error coming up on using this code on my local environment: `stock-transfer.php?edit=1:645 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`

Comment: Sounds like you used `trigger` instead of `triggerHandler` or just forgot to write `return $.ajax({ ...` inside the event listener. @sohal07